# Convert a date format with month name into proper date with pandas

Tags: pandas, date, format

I have a date column having values like `'November 4, 2016'`

Can we convert it into proper date using pandas like this format `'4/11/16'`

using pandas to_datetime or any other funtion.

Comment: Where is the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the question? Please include it to the question. Also make sure to read [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

If need convert column to datetimes use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%B %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `df`:

```
In [463]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['November 4, 2016', 'December 1, 2017']})

In [464]: df
Out[464]: 
               date
0  November 4, 2016
1  December 1, 2017
```

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
In [469]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%B %d, %Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')

In [479]: df
Out[479]: 
       date
0  04/11/16
1  01/12/17
```